# Generating random number for a distribution of a real data?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy, probability-density

I have a set of real data and I want use this data to find a probability distribution and then use their property to generate some random points according to their pdf. A sample of my data set is as following:

```
#Mag Weight
21.9786 3.6782
24.0305 6.1120
21.9544 4.2225
23.9383 5.1375
23.9352 4.6499
23.0261 5.1355
23.8682 5.9932
24.8052 4.1765
22.8976 5.1901
23.9679 4.3190
25.3362 4.1519
24.9079 4.2090
23.9851 5.1951
22.2094 5.1570
22.3452 5.6159
24.0953 6.2697
24.3901 6.9299
24.1789 4.0222
24.2648 4.4997
25.3931 3.3920
25.8406 3.9587
23.1427 6.9398
21.2985 7.7582
25.4807 3.1112
25.1935 5.0913
25.2136 4.0578
24.6990 3.9899
23.5299 4.6788
24.0880 7.0576
24.7931 5.7088
25.1860 3.4825
24.4757 5.8500
24.1398 4.9842
23.4947 4.4730
20.9806 5.2717
25.9470 3.4706
25.0324 3.3879
24.7186 3.8443
24.3350 4.9140
24.6395 5.0757
23.9181 4.9951
24.3599 4.1125
24.1766 5.4360
24.8378 4.9121
24.7362 4.4237
24.4119 6.1648
23.8215 5.9184
21.5394 5.1542
24.0081 4.2308
24.5665 4.6922
23.5827 5.4992
23.3876 6.3692
25.6872 4.5055
23.6629 5.4416
24.4821 4.7922
22.7522 5.9513
24.0640 5.8963
24.0361 5.6406
24.8687 4.5699
24.8795 4.3198
24.3486 4.5305
21.0720 9.5246
25.2960 3.0828
23.8204 5.8605
23.3732 5.1161
25.5097 2.9010
24.9206 4.0999
24.4140 4.9073
22.7495 4.5059
24.3394 3.5061
22.0560 5.5763
25.4404 5.4916
25.4795 4.4089
24.1772 3.8626
23.6042 4.7476
23.3537 6.4804
23.6842 4.3220
24.1895 3.6072
24.0328 4.3273
23.0243 5.6789
25.7042 4.4493
22.1983 6.1868
22.3661 5.9132
20.9426 4.8079
20.3806 10.1128
25.0105 4.4296
23.6648 6.6482
25.2780 4.4933
24.6870 4.4836
25.4565 4.0990
25.0415 3.9384
24.6098 4.6057
24.7796 4.2042
```

How could I do this? My first attempt was to fit a polynomial to the binned data and find the probability distribution of weights in each magnitude bin, but I reckon it might be a smarter way to do it. For instance, using `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` for sampling data from the given distribution but I don't know how it can work and there are not enough examples.

**Update:**
As I got a lot of comments to use `KDE`, I used `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` and I got the following results.
[image]

I am wondering whether it is a good probability distribution to represent the property of my data? First, how could I test it, and second, whether there is a possibility to fit more than one **gaussian kde** with `scipy.stats`?

Comment: You might want to look at Kernel Density Estimation. Wikipedia has an example using scipy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation#Example_in_Python. I don't know enough about the scipy implementation to help any further.

Comment: `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` has a `resample` method to sample from the kernel density

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) If you have an idea about the distribution from which these data are sampled, then fit that distribution to the data (i.e., adjust parameters via maximum likelihood or whatever) and then sample that.

(2) For more nearly empirical approach, select one datum at random (with equal probability) and then pretend it is the center of a little Gaussian bump, and sample from that bump. This is equivalent to constructing a kernel density estimate and sampling from that. You will have to pick a standard deviation for the bumps.

(3) For an entirely empirical approach, select one datum at random (with equal probability). This is equivalent to assuming the empirical distribution is the same as the actual distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question. What do you reckon?

Comment: How could I get certain that this probability is a good representative of my data and another question: If I use `scipy.stats.guassian_kde`, is it possible that from estimated **kde**, I put another sample that just has for instance `Mag` and then extract from this probability the distribution of `weight`?

Comment: @Dalek "How could I get certain that this probability is a good representative of my data" -- you can't. All models are wrong, some are useful (John Tukey). It is up to you to decide what's "useful" for your purposes.

Comment: @Dalek "from estimated kde, I put another sample that just has for instance Mag and then extract from this probability the distribution of weight" -- yes. What you are looking for is called the conditional distribution of weight given Mag. The conditional distribution of a KDE will probably have a simple form; I don't know it offhand, but I can work it out. Let me know if you're interested.

Comment: My original problem is that, I know there is an underlying relation between `Mag` and `Weight`, and I assumed the best way to find it according to the comment is the empirical distribution. So my next move is to generate a mock catalogue for my research based on the estimated `PDF` with KDE. So I generate some random `Mag` based on knowing that they would follow some conditions and then I want to use `Mag` and `PDF` to sample `weight` for the given `Mag`. How it should be done and do you think it is a right approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55640/discussion-between-robert-dodier-and-dalek).

Comment: I posted another question regarding to my problem with more details. I appreciate if you take a look.

Answer (score 0):

What is this data representing?

SciPy won't help you decide what type of distribution to use. That choice is motivated by where your data is coming from. Once you do decide on a distribution (or you could try several), then you can easily do something like a scipy.optimize.curve_fit on your data to decide on the optimal parameters to give to feed into pdf class in scipy.stats so that it matches your data. Then use a scipy continuous random variable to generate new points from your distribution.

Also, a polynomial is not a probability density function since it is not normalized (integral over all x diverges). Polynomial fits are not going to help you, as far as I know.

Comment: I can normalized the probability density, right? I want to find a way to generate mock catalogue, based on real data and get an idea of how likely is to have an object with given magnitude and weight and sample my data based on both **errors** and **distribution**.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating a histogram of the data? That will give you a sense of the shape of the density function, at which point you can try fitting the data to a known distribution. Once you have a fitted distribution, you can generate pseudo-random variates to get a 'sanity check', perform a nonparametric test like the Kolmogorov–Smirnov.

So, I would take the following steps:

1. Create a histogram
2. Determine characteristics of the data (summary stats, etc.).
3. Try to fit to parametric distribution.
4. Try to fit to nonparametric distribution.
5. Conduct hypothesis tests to rate the fit.

Comment: "perform a nonparametric test like the Kolmogorov–Smirnov." -- this is useless. A hypothesis test must reject the null hypothesis if there is any difference and the sample is large enough. As it is impossible for OP to know the exact distribution involved, the result of the test can only be "you have/don't have a large enough sample". That simply isn't useful in any way.